# Find a User by Username OR Email with One Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

So I have a `User` model with both Username and Email columns. I'm looking to create a search function for this database such that one user can find another by entering in the other user's Username OR Email address. I'd like to have the search be one field such that you can type either in and simply click the search submit button.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to do this. I imagine a regex would be involved in the search function, which would look like this but with another `if` statement:

**User Model**

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('username LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
User.where('name LIKE :query OR email LIKE :query', query: "%#{search}%")
```

Comment: Follow up question for you. What if I want to have an exact match such it only returns a user if the whole username or email are entered?

Comment: Then do `User.where('name LIKE :query OR email LIKE :query', query: search)` without %'s

Comment: Shorter syntax for that case: `User.where('name = :query OR email = :query', query: search)`

Answer (score 0):

```
User.where("email like ? or user_name like ?", "%#{search}%","%#{search}%")
```